# PHP CS Fixer Creating Whitespace Between Array Key and Arrow Pointer

Tags: php, laravel, php-8, php-cs-fixer

Using Laravel, my kernel file has my `$routeMiddleware` property array as normal.

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  'access' => \App\Middleware\AllowAccess::class,
  'auth' => \App\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
  ...
```

is being changed to this run I run fixer:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  'access'         => \App\Middleware\AllowAccess::class,
  'auth'             => \App\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
  ...
```

My fixer rule set looks like so:

```php
$config->setRules([
  '@PSR2' => true,
  'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],
  'ordered_imports' => ['sort_algorithm' => 'length'],
  'no_unused_imports' => true,
])
->setIndent("\t")
->setFinder($finder);
```

What rule can I add to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found interesting rules about arrays [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/4060).

May you try some of them and tell me if it matches your issue ?

```
    'no_multiline_whitespace_around_double_arrow' => true,
    'trim_array_spaces'                   => true,
    'object_operator_without_whitespace'  => true,
```